# How to Bind database integer value to TextBox in FormView control?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

On my page I have FormView control, and I am binding Integer database field to the TextBox that's residing inside a FormView's EditItemTemplate.

```
<FormView ...>
    <EditItemTemplate> 
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtDiameter" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Diameter") %>' />
        ... 
    <EditItemTemplate>
    ... 
</FormView>
```

My problem is that when Diameter field is null, the txtDiameter gets value of empty string. When I click Update command (if I didn't provide any numerical value in txtDiameter), a client error is raised

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:  is not a valid value for Int32.

I found some post from 2005 that claims that this is happening due to some bug. Well, now is 2012. The only way I figured how to deal with this is by using `FormView_ItemUpdating` event, to circle through all problematic values and convert them from String.Empty to null.

I am just little suspicious that it's maybe not necessary. Is there another way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the editor's Value property instead:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtDiameter" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Diameter") %>' />
```

Does this work?